# Closure of the diagonal is an equivalence relation

Tags: ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\overline{\Delta_X} \subseteq X \times X$ the closure of its diagonal.
Then $\overline{\Delta_X}$ is the graph of an equivalence relation on $X$.
This statement can be found in Borceux's *Handbook of Categorical Algebra I*, chapter 3, page 96, as he introduces adjoint functors.

I'm currently trying to prove this. Reflexivity is clear, and so is symmetry, for $(x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$ is an automorphism of $X \times X$. However, I'm not sure how to prove transitivity. Here's what I found.

Not belonging to $\overline{\Delta_X}$ is the same as being separable by open subsets of $X$ : indeed, $(a,b) \notin \overline{\Delta_X}$ iff there exists $U,V$ open subsets of $X$ such that $(a,b) \in U \times V \subseteq (X \times X) \setminus \overline{\Delta_X}$, that is iff there exists $U,V$ open subsets of $X$ such that $a \in U$,$ b \in V$ but $U \cap V = \varnothing$. Thus it seems to me that the statement is false : taking $X = \{x,y,z\}$ with basis $\{x\},\{z\}$, we have $(x,y),(y,z) \in \overline{\Delta_X}$ and yet $(x,z) \notin \overline{\Delta_X}$.

Thank you for clearing my mind.

Edit : It seems that this statement really is false, as [Eric Wofsey](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/86856/eric-wofsey) suggests in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2763947/3835) at math.SE.

Answer (score 4):

The set $\{1,2,3\}$ for which the open subsets are $\emptyset$, $\{1\}$, $\{3\}$, $\{1,3\}$, $\{1,2,3\}$, is a topological space for which the closure of the diagonal is $\{1,2,3\}^2\smallsetminus\{(1,3),(3,1)\}=\{1,2\}^2\cup\{2,3\}^2$, which is not an equivalence relation.

Possibly more intuitively it can be viewed as the quotient of $\mathbf{R}$ by the equivalence relation $x\simeq y$ if $\exists t>0$: $x=ty$.

Comment: It is also the Alexandroff topology on a span poset, the first poset where the relation $\{(x,y)\ |\ x \leq y \text{ or } x \geq y\}$ is not transitive.